# Fibonacci with n numbers instead of 2

Tags: code-golf, fibonacci

### How to

Given an integer `n` start with `n` ones (i.e. 4 -> `1 1 1 1`). Then sum up the
last `n` numbers, and repeat.

For `n = 4` this looks like this:

Start with `1 1 1 1`, sum up the last 4 numbers resulting in `1 1 1 1 4`, then
sum up the last 4 numbers resulting in `1 1 1 1 4 7`, then sum up the last 4 numbers resulting in `1 1 1 1 4 7 13` and so on.

### The task

Write a program or function that produces the first 30 numbers of this sequence given `n` as input (either as argument, stdin, command line argument, on the stack, ...)

The 30 terms for n = 4 are:

`1 1 1 1 4 7 13 25 49 94 181 349 673 1297 2500 4819 9289 17905 34513 66526 128233 247177 476449 918385 1770244 3412255 6577333 12678217 24438049 47105854`

The 30 terms for n = 5 are:

`1 1 1 1 1 5 9 17 33 65 129 253 497 977 1921 3777 7425 14597 28697 56417 110913 218049 428673 842749 1656801 3257185 6403457 12588865 24749057 48655365`

In case `n` is smaller than two or larger than 30 the behaviour can be undefined.

Comment: Can the function return more than 30 elements, or must it return exactly 30 elements?

Comment: No, exactly 30. But it's a duplicate. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 64 bytes

```javascript
f=(n,i,a=[])=>i>29?a:f(n,-~i,[...a,(g=_=>n--&&a[--i]+g())()||1])
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VchBCsIwEAXQvQcp8zETUHShMPEgIchQmzBSErHiqnj16Na3fHd96zI@7fHi2m5T71moOnMqMUGChf3pouf8O/6Yi957dVTkKqEyD4NGZkvbQgBhXXcJfWx1afPk51Yo0wHY/M8R6F8)

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 12 bytes

```
Å1 30FDO¸«ć,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//cKuhgrGBm4v/oR2HVh9p1/n/3xQA)

**Explanation**

```
Å1            # push a list of n 1s
  30F         # 30 times do:
     D        # duplicate
      O       # sum
       ¸«     # append
         ć,   # extract and print the head
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Tidy](https://github.com/ConorOBrien-Foxx/Tidy), 35 bytes

```
{x:30^recur(*tile(x,c(1)),sum@c,x)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYvNCsIwEAbvfYqPnHZtBH/AQ6Hie4hCWROI1AaSLVZKnz3mMjADo@H1Kx5dX9alOx@eycmcaKdhdLRYoSOzzfPnJnbhrRh1WSFDdtk0KnXD/WRxeTQ@JnG0YujwTUHdOFHWRAOjhcH@WtHiHcNEvkZb1TBjQ5ygwuUP)

### Explanation

```
{x:30^recur(*tile(x,c(1)),sum@c,x)}
{x:                               }   lambda taking parameter `x`
   30^                                take the first 30 terms of...
      recur(                     )        a recursive function
            *tile(x,c(1))                 whose seed is `x` `1`s
                                x         with a window of `x`
                          sum@c           and the functor takes the sum of its arguments
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 60 bytes

```python
lambda n:reduce(lambda a,c:a+[sum(a[-n:])],'.'*(30-n),[1]*n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSHPqig1pTQ5VQPKT9RJtkrUji4uzdVIjNbNs4rVjNVR11PX0jA20M3T1Ik2jNXK0/xfUJSZV6KQpmGiyQVjmmr@BwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), 81 bytes

```
import StdEnv
$n=reverse(while((>)30o length)(\l=[sum(take n l):l])(repeatn n 1))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCsIwEADQ3a@4oUNuEBRxEeKkQ8Gtozoc6dkGL5eSpBV/3tj1Dc8Jk9YQ@1kYAnmtPkwxFehKf9Vl06hNvHDKbD6jFzbmjIddBGEdyojmIfae52AKvRkUBE/yRJN4Yiq6wh6xdoXW0EIDx/pzL6Eh1217q5evUvAu/wE)

`(repeatn n 1)` gives us `n` ones in a list, which we repeatedly prepend the sum of the first `n` elements to (with `(\l=[sum(take n l):l])`), while it has less than 30 elements.
As the list is backwards, we reverse it and return.